# Matlab struct of vectors to vector of struct conversion

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matlab-struct

How can I convert arrays x(1:N), y(1:N) into a structure S(1:N) with fields .x and .y in a fast way without for-loop?
I can easily convert x, y into a struct of arrays:

```
S.x = x; S.y = y;
```

Since I need to work with individual sets of (xi, yi), how can I convert this to an array of struct?
I have found a solution to do this via table type, but I don't like this solution:

```
S = table2struct(struct2table(S))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `struct` directly after first converting `x` and `y` to cell arrays. When the values passed to `struct` are cell arrays, then this results in a multi-element `struct` with the same dimensions as that cell array.

```
S = struct('x', num2cell(x), 'y', num2cell(y));
```

Comment: Thanks, this takes about 0.2 sec to create a struct vector from two 1000000x1 vectors vs 0.7 sec with table2struct-struct2table approach.